# If Earth had a sideways axial tilt (like Uranus), would Earth still have tornadoes?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, earth, weather, axial-tilt

Imagine Earth was hit hard by some force so devastating that Earth now has an axial tilt of 90.0 degrees, a far cry from the usual 23.5 degree. The same force somehow eliminates the Moon. In my story, Earth now obliquity oscillates between 89 to 91 degrees and will remain so for another 13000 baktun cycle of the Maya Long Count calendar. With the tides and seasons out of the way, I am wondering: could tornados still form? If so, what mechanism would drive such vortices?

Comment: What makes you believe that there is a link between seasons and tides on one hand and tornado formation on the other?

Comment: This needs an edit; it is unreadable. Also, a planet's tilt does not directly affect tornadoes. Finally, this isn't worldbuilding; please put it somewhere else.

Comment: @SEistoopoliticallycorrect Other than the weird choice of using the Mayan calendar, I'd say the question is fairly clear.  It seems to be based on a false assumption about tornadoes, but it's entirely readable.

Comment: I agree with @MishaR , this is perfectly on-topic. We are designing / explaining the weather patterns for a clearly defined world. It also seems like the OP might be drawing a link between the Coriolis Effect and the existence of tornadoes which seems like a clear idea for readers to address / debunk.

Comment: @MishaR Definitely on topic. Still needed editing. These things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @SRM I did not want to get pedantic regarding Zxyrra's comment, since I agree with it.  But, since you're pushing the point, I actually never said anything about whether or not the question is on topic.  Nor did I imply that this is in conflict with editing.  My comment was in regard to the question's readability.  However, if we're talking about editing, I think some of the edits you've made alter the narrative of the question without necessity.  In my opinion, this oversteps the bounds of good editing

Comment: @MishaR I did that deliberately to remove how the tilt happened in order to make it clear that the question was about the world after it settles down and not tornados during the tilting. That was one of the key ambiguities in the original. The narrative flavor was clouding the question, so I removed it. I’ve been doing this for enough years, this is the kind of edit that I know is borderline but I think I have enough perspective to make. Author is free to revert if I’ve overstepped, obviously.

Comment: @SRM *I’ve been doing this for enough years* - 3.5 years, according to your profile :)  While it is definitely several years, it is still well within the bounds of being able to make a bad edit.  And, while I respect your perspective, I respectfully disagree with your edit.  But, while I agree that bad edits are best not made to begin with (since the original wording may likely reflect the actual story the OP is trying to write), it is also true that the author is free to change it back.  Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @MishaR 3 here. More elsewhere outside of SE. Maintaining author intent is never easy when editing, in any venue. And good editors can and do  disagree with each other, frequently. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[A planet's tilt is not directly linked with tornado formation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornadogenesis)

More important factors include things like the overall energy of the storm and pressure dynamics.

Due to the proximity to the sun and the abundance of water, this skewampus version of earth *will still have weather*. This includes tornadoes. (It will likely not be the current weather patterns, though!)

Comment: And *yes*, an earth that isn't tilted is skewampus!

Comment: Bonus points for use of word ”skewampus”!